# Inserting json array into mysql with foreach

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a json array I wan't to insert into my sql database, but I am not too experienced with php so I might be doing multiple things wrong.

PHP:

```
<?php

//Runescape API Class
require_once 'assets/api/Runescape_API.class.php';
$rsapi = new Runescape_API;

//Clan Members
if($ressource = $rsapi->getClanMembers("Made+in+norway")){
    $result["getClanMembers"] = $ressource;
}


$obj = json_decode($result["getClanMembers"],true);

echo $obj;

//MYSQL Connection
require_once('assets/inc/link.php');


foreach ((array) $obj as $item) {
       mysqli_query($db, "INSERT INTO `minrs`.`members` (name, rank, xp, kills) VALUES ('".$item['name']."', '".$item['rank']."', '".$item['xp']."', '".$item['kills']."')");
    }

?>
```

JSON:

```
{
    "getClanMembers": [
     {
         "name": "Benjamin",
         "rank": "Owner",
         "xp": "488731559",
         "kills": "0"
     },
     {
         "name": "tiMMe",
         "rank": "Deputy Owner",
         "xp": "341737592",
         "kills": "0"
     },
     {
         "name": "uncel dolan",
         "rank": "Overseer",
         "xp": "551290158",
         "kills": "4"
     }
  ]
}
```

Error I am currently getting:

> json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

I've tried multiple "soloutions" but they just gave me more errors so this is the code I started out with.

Appreciate any help I can get, Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what part of the process is failing, or even what errors you are getting.

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: `print_r($result["getClanMembers"]);`

Comment: `var_dump($result["getClanMembers"]);` isn't a string.

Comment: print_r($result["getClanMembers"]); -> https://pastebin.com/pCzDzcz9

Comment: So `json_decode($result["getClanMembers"],true);` is not necessary :) And loop around `$result["getClanMembers"]`